# How can i create a menu dropdown in MVC using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

what i want to do is.....i have a menu like this

```
       <div id="menucontainer">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("NewMovies","NewMovies","Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

"NewMovies" menu should have some movies list..

now i want to have a drop down menu to "NewMovies" using jquery ...can any one help me with this please

Comment: this is the first time i am working on an MVC app ......i worked wiht menus in web applications....i googled a lot hot to do it in MVC,But I dnt get what i want

Comment: how you did it before MVC? it doesn't work now?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use something different of what the default MVC3 menu brings you.
Pick up a whole new JQuery menu [here](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/03/jquery-menu-plugins.html) or [here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/)

It will be simple:

1. Add a new `partial view` your html `_layout` so it can be on all pages.
2. Put a `<div>` tag with the html of one of this menus in the `partial view`
3. Add the related **CSS**
4. Add the related **JS**
5. *Optional* if the information of the menu comes from database, you can use a `Controller` and `JSON` call to fill your menu, but this is a bit more complicated

Hope it helps, good luck!